# Accessing 3D array in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a nxmx2 array in numpy, called `T`. I also have the indices array `i, j, k`. For instance,

```
I=[0,2], J=[0,1,2,4], K=[0,1,0,1]
```

I want, for every `T[i,:,:]`, the vector that has the elements `[j,k]`, i.e., the elements in positions `[0,0], [1,1], [2,0], [4,1]`, and to save this into a 2D array.

What's the fastest (in runtime) way of doing this?

Comment: `T[ [[0],[2]], J, K]` should do it.   If `I` is a (2,1) array, then it will `broadcast` with the others to fetch a (2,4) set of values.

Comment: @hpaulj I cannot do [[0],[2]], I can only type I

Comment: `np.array(I)[:,None]` will do the same.  You want a (2,1) index array.  Take some time to read the `numpy` basic docs.